# Java FileNotFound Exception error even if I have specified the right path

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

The file can't be found and I don't have to specify the file location because it's in the same directory as the class Test.

The code :

```
File myFile = new File("aaa.txt");

boolean isExisting = myFile.exists();
System.out.println(isExisting);

try {
  FileReader f = new FileReader(myFile);
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(f);

  String line = bf.readLine();

  while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = bf.readLine();
  }

  bf.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("Can't find file");

  // e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Error");
}
```

The error (if not catched) :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: aaa.txt (The specified file cannot be found)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:75)
at Testing/Packageeee.Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

They're all in the same directory

[image: picture]

Comment: _"I don't have to specify the file location because it's in the same directory"_ - Not necessarily true.

Comment: Use this line to see which directory you're actually running in: `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());`

Comment: Assuming that the file is also included in the same location as your `*.class` files (or within the resulting Jar file), then it is an embedded resource and can't be referenced as a `File`, instead, you should be using `Class#getResource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly running from the root of your project. Not from the same directory as your text file.

Assuming that `aaa.txt` is in a directory called `src` the following snippet should work:

```
  String baseDirectory;
  try {
    baseDirectory = new File("./src").getCanonicalPath();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  

  File myFile = new File(baseDirectory, "aaa.txt");
```

Comment: After many tries and after combining your code with FileReader and BufferedReader it works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getResourceAsStream` on your main class to get an `InputStream` for the file.

```java
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        Test.class.getResourceAsStream("aaa.txt")));
```